Simple instance illustrating significance of Langlands dual group without getting into the Langlands program?
To a reductive group $G$, one can associate its "Langlands dual" group ${}^L G$. The Langlands dual group is notably important in the Langlands program. But it seems to me that the Langlands dual group itself should be something I can appreciate in a much more elementary way, without requiring me to develop any kind of understanding of the Langlands program.
Question 1: Is there some elementary (and in particular, not-requiring-an-understanding-of-the-Langlands-program) way to illustrate the significance of the Langlands dual group? (Ideally some kind of theorem which relates something about $G$ to something about ${}^L G$, or gives an action of data associated to one on the data associated to the other, or something like that. Perhaps any theorem of such a form ipso facto has something to do with the Langlands progam, but even in this case, such a theorem should be something I can appreciate without needing to understand the Langlands program as a whole.)
For context, the extent of my current understanding is basically that there is a canonical involution on the collection of all possible "root data", and this lifts to an involution on (say) reductive Lie groups over $\mathbb C$ which we call "Langlands duality".
Question 2: What kind of functoriality properties does $G \mapsto {}^L G$ have?
Question 3: I think the simplest case is supposed to be $G = GL_1$, which is Langlands self-dual. In this case, is there any way to see the self-duality at play? (for instance, if $G \mapsto {}^L G$ were contravariantly functorial, maybe this contravariance would carry through to some kind of representation-theoretic data associated to $G$ and ${}^L G$).
Bonus points if your answer can be used as an entry point toward getting an understanding of the Langlands program.

I have no interest in the Langlands program, but the dual root datum is relevant in the representation theory of finite groups of Lie type (Deligne-Lusztig theory), where you can define the analogue of ${}^L G$ over a finite field. I'm not sure if this is any more elementary, but because of my own interests it is more approachable to me..

You may change the notations, $^{L}G$ always refers to the Langlands $L$-group but not the Langlands dual group…

Do you care about the cohomology of $p$-adic groups? Kottwitz proves (as a sort of generalization of Tate—Nakayama) that for a reductive group $G$ over a $p$-adic local field $F$, one has that $H^1(F,G)$ (i.e., the Galois cohomology of $G$) is computed as the Pontryagin dual of $\pi_0(Z(\widehat{G})^\Gamma)$, where $\Gamma$ is the Galois group of $F$.

The $L$-group is not functorial in the contravariant way one might expect (e.g., think about the inclusion of a maximal torus), but it is functorial in homomorphisms with normal image. Again, I learned this from Kottwitz. Both of these results are in his paper “Stable Trace Formula: Cuspidal Tempered Terms”.

I don't know if it counts as simple, but there's Calder Daenzer, Erik Van Erp, T-Duality for Langlands Dual Groups https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0763

As Atiyah firstly observed, a notion that is similar to the Langlands dual appeared in Goddard–Nuyts–Olive’s study of the electric-magnetic duality.
For a simple non-abelian gauge group $G$, they considered a theory in which the gauge group is effectively reduced to a maximal torus $T\subset G$. If this reduction only occurs away from the singularity, one can define a magnetic charge that classifies $T$-bundles (rather than $G$-bundles) over a two-sphere, which takes values in $\pi_1(T)$. For a torus $T$, it’s the same as $\operatorname{Hom}(U(1),T)$, where the $U(1)$ is the abelian gauge group.
On the other hand, once one assumes that the gauge symmetry is effectively reduced from $G$ to a maximal torus $T$, one should classify the electric charge by a representation of $T$. Irreducible representations of the abelian group $T$ are 1-dimensional, so they correspond to elements of $\operatorname{Hom}(T,U(1))$. Then one has:

Electric charge: $\operatorname{Hom}(T,U(1))$
Magnetic charge: $\operatorname{Hom}(U(1),T)$.

Moreover, they went on to make the observation that attracted the interest of Atiyah: For any simple Lie group $G$, there is another simple Lie group $G^\vee$, with maximal torus $T^\vee$ such that
$$\operatorname{Hom}(T,U(1))=\operatorname{Hom}(U(1),T^\vee)$$
and reciprocally
$$\operatorname{Hom}(U(1),T)=\operatorname{Hom}(T^\vee,U(1)).$$
In other words, the electric charge of $G$ is the magnetic charge of $G^\vee$ and vice-versa. This observation was later developed by Kapustin–Witten and others, then came to be a special case of the geometric Langlands today.

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$As coLaideronnette points out in the comments, ${}^L G$ usually refers not to the Langlands dual group but to the $L$-group, which is something more complicated, a semidirect product of the Langlands dual $G^\vee$ with a Galois group or Weil group. I guess terminology here is not entirely consistent: Wikipedia refers to ${}^LG$ as the Langlands dual group, but means the more complicated thing. Certainly if your goal is to understand something as elementary as possible you want to understand $G^\vee$.

The simplest case of the Langlands program is that for a reductive group $G$ over an algebraically closed field, irreducible algebraic representations of $G$ are naturally in bijection with algebraic homomorphisms $\GL_1 \to G^\vee$ (up to conjugation). This is an example of "an action of data associated to one on the data associated to the other, or something like that" but not a theorem because I haven't described a characterizing property of this bijection. Probably there is a good characterizing property. One property the bijection has is that the highest weight of summands of the tensor product of two irreducible representations agrees with the highest coweight of homomorphisms you can obtain by conjugating the two homomorphisms until they commute and then multiplying them.

This works just because, by highest weight theory, irreducible algebraic representations are classified by algebraic homomorphisms $T \to \GL_1$ for $T$ a maximal torus, modulo the Weyl group. Homomorphisms $T \to \GL_1$ form a group, isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$ for some $n$.  Similarly homomorphisms $\GL_1 \to G^\vee$ are necessarily conjugate to homomorphisms $\GL_1 \to T^\vee$, well-defined modulo the Weyl group, and homomorphisms $\GL_1\to T^\vee$ form a group, isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$ for some $n$. $G^\vee$ is chosen exactly so that these groups are isomorphic in a way respecting the action of the Weyl group.

$G^\vee$ is contravariantly functorial with respect to isomorphisms of $G$, in such a way that every inner automorphism is sent to the identity. This can be seen from the explicit construction of the dual using root systems.

It's easier to see in $(\GL_1)^n$, or even better in the category of groups of the form $(\GL_1)^n$ for some $n$ with morphisms algebraic homomorphisms. This category is equivalent to the category of finitely generated free abelian groups, which has a contravariant equivalence of categories to itself sending a group $G$ to the dual group $\operatorname{Hom}(G, \mathbb Z)$. This contravariant equivalence of categories, on the algebraic group side, is Langlands duality.



I think it is explained by your parenthesis, but I don't understand "inner automorphisms always induce the identity on Borels (but send one Borel to a different Borel, but this doesn't matter)."  Even an inner automorphism that preserves a Borel subgroup usually won't act as the identity on it, so obviously you didn't mean what seems to be the literal wording, but I can't figure what you did mean.

@LSpice: Yes, this is a good point. The point (as I am sure you know) Is that you get an inner automorphism of the Borel but the inner automorphisms act trivially on the data used to construct the dual. Maybe I should just say that this is true and not try to explain it as I don't think I can without just writing out the full construction.

Are you sure that $G \leadsto G^\vee$ is functorial?  Certainly there's a map $\operatorname{Out}(G) \to \operatorname{Out}(G^\vee)$, but I don't know how to convert that to a map $\operatorname{Out}(G) \to \operatorname{Aut}(G^\vee)$ without choosing a pinning of $G^\vee$.

@LSpice But $G^\vee$ comes with a canonical pinning.  For $G$ a reductive group once we choose a pinning we get a Cartain matrix and then outer automorphisms of the group give permutations that conjugate the Cartan matrix to itself (i.e. automorphisms of the Dynkin diagrams).  From this we can calculate the Cartan matrix of the dual root system and then we construct $G^\vee$ as the split reductive group with that root system constructed using Chevalley generators and Serre relations. This construction is functorial in the root system.

@LSpice This is needed to construct ${}^L G$. From an algebraic group $G$ over a nonclosed field we get a map from Galois to the outer automorphism group of $G$. We construct ${}^L G$ as a semidirect product of Galois with $G^\vee$, for which we need a map from Galois to $\operatorname{Aut}( G^\vee)$, and we do this using a map $\operatorname{Out}(G) \to \operatorname{Aut}(G^\vee)$.

If G is a a group scheme over k, then an “algebraic representation” is a map of group schemes over k, $G \to GL_n$? Or is it some condition in a complex representation?

@TimCampion, re, a finite-dimensional representation, yes.  Representations are locally finite (by usual definition), so that will do.  But it is also common to define a $G$-representation as a $k$-vector space $M$ together with a $G(A)$-module structure on $M \otimes_k A$ for all $k$-algebras $A$; or, equivalently if $G$ is affine, as a comodule for the ring $k[G]$ of regular functions.

@WillSawin, re, OK, thanks.  (Sorry for not responding earlier; I was getting the "site is in read-only mode" issue.)

@TimCampion The answers to your questions are yes and yes. As LSpice said, it means the group scheme thing, but it can equally well be presented as a complex representation whose matrix coefficients are polynomial functions. In the context of reductive groups I would normally call this just a representation but of course in the Langlands program we often consider representations of these groups that are merely continuous.

@LSpice Thanks for explaining that, I was suffering from this also.

Are we assuming that $k$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$? I didn’t realize we were assuming it was of characteristic 0.

@TimCampion When you said "some condition in a complex representation" I assumed you meant $k=\mathbb C$. That characterization of algebraic is best if $k=\mathbb C$, though you're right it works for subfields of $\mathbb C$ also. Everything else should be fine in characteristic $p$, I believe.

@TimCampion The general version of "some condition in a complex representation" is of course "some condition on a representation over $k$" with the condition being that the matrix coefficients are polynomial functions. This works as long as $k$ is infinite but we already assumed $k$ is algebraically closed so we're fine.

In addition to other good comments and answers, the historical (and, I think, conceptual) precursor to $^L G$ is just the Satake isomorphism from spherical Hecke algebras on a p-adic reductive group to a simpler algebra. Via "Satake parameters", later, "Langlands parameters".
Due to intertwinings (indexed by the spherical Weyl group...) among (unramified) principal series, generically there are ambiguities here...
And, even decades ago, the parameters of the image had certain obvious symmetries, dictating the target group in which they might be a semi-simple conjugacy class.
Conclusion: an insightful way to clean up and organize this turns out to be (some version of) the Langlands dual... at least without worrying about the Galois part.
Yes, meanwhile, the Galois part, while slightly justified by some base-change things, is based on the fundamental hope that (non-abelian) Artin L-functions are automorphic... :)

Or, more precisely, Satake is an isomorphism from the spherical Hecke algebra of $G(\mathbb Q_p)$ to the representation ring of $G^\vee(\mathbb C)$. This leads to some interesting formulae for changes of basis from one algebra to another involving Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials and allows one to study one algebra using another.
